# Using lastInsertID() in my database class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to figure out how to get the last insert id with the database class I'm using and can't seem to get it right. Keep getting  "Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()"

Here's  how I call it.

```
require_once '../classes/pdo.php'; 
$sql="insert into accounts(account_email,account_password) values(:email,:password)"; 
$values=array(':email'=>'jay.garrick@email.com',':password'=>'blah'); 
$res = DB::run($sql,$values); 
$id = $res->lastInsertId(); 
echo $id;
```

Here's my class.

```
class DB {
protected static $instance = null; 
protected function __construct() {}
protected function __clone() {}
public $pdo; 
public $lastInsertId = null; 
public static function instance()
{
    if(self::$instance == null) 
    {
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        );
        //$options = array_replace($default_options,$options); 

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
        self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt); 
    }
    return self::$instance; 
}
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
}

public static function run($sql, $args = NULL)
{
    if(!$args)
    {
        return self::instance()->query($sql); 
    }
    $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute($args);  
    return $stmt; 
}
```

}

Comment: It's a method of the `PDO` class, not of `PDOStatement`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: So how would i get the last insert id and use it outside of the class?

Comment: Via your `PDO` instance, which you got stored in `self::$instance`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense